# Hallar camino nodo raiz a nodo específico en un árbol binario en Prolog

Tags: prolog, árboles, árboles-binarios

Buenas,

Quiero hallar la manera de poder devolver una lista con los nodos que hay en un **camino** desde el nodo raíz del árbol a un nodo específico haciendo haciendo uso **únicamente** de los siguientes constructores y selectores

```
vacio([]).
raiz([_,N,_], N).
hi([HI,_,_],HI).
hd([_,_,HD],HD).
hazarbol(R,HI,HD,[HI,R,HD])
```

Se define un árbol binario en Prolog de la siguiente manera:

```
A4 = [[[[[],1,[]],5,[]],
7,
[[],3,[[],4,[]]]],
6,
[[[],10,[]],
8,
[[[],9,[]],11,[[],2,[]]]]]
```

Cuyo aspecto es el siguiente
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

La última prueba que he hecho ( siendo incorrecta ) es la siguiente:

```
padre(N,Abn,P) :- hi(Abn,HI), raiz(HI,N), raiz(Abn,P).
padre(N,Abn,P) :- hd(Abn,HD), raiz(HD,N), raiz(Abn,P).

padre(N,Abn,P) :- hi(Abn,HI), padre(N,HI,P).
padre(N,Abn,P) :- hd(Abn,HD), padre(N,HD,P).

caminohasta(N,[L,N,R],N).
caminohasta(N,Abn,[L]) :-  padre(N,Abn,P), append([P],L),caminohasta(P,Abn,L).
```

Pero como output me devuelve `procedure` camino(A,B,C)' does not exist`

¿Alguna idea de cómo puedo proceder?

Muchas gracias por adelantado

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El caso base es llegar al nodo buscado:

```
caminohasta(N,[_,N,_],[N]).
```

En el caso general, se añade el nodo visitado como cabeza del camino, y el camino desde cada rama como cola:

```
caminohasta(N,[L,X,_],[X|C]) :- caminohasta(N,L,C).
caminohasta(N,[_,X,R],[X|C]) :- caminohasta(N,R,C).
```

Algunas consideraciones sobre tu solución:

- Estás buscando el camino de abajo a arriba, lo cual es más ineficiente, debido a que cada vez que buscas el padre de un nodo tienes que buscarlo desde la raíz. Si buscas de arriba a abajo y, haciendo uso del no determinismo, es más cómodo y sólo tienes que explorar una vez el árbol.
- El predicado `append/2` no existe, y tampoco parece que lo hayas definido (ni tiene mucho sentido). La concatenación (`append/3`) necesita tres listas, y es verdad cuando la tercera lista es la concatenación de las dos primeras.
- El error que recibes es por lanzar un objetivo con el predicado `camino/3`, cuando en tu código las cláusulas tienen el nombre `caminohasta`.

Comment: Gracias por contestar tan rápido, me estás ayudando mucho ! Una duda que tengo, si por ejemplo quisiera hacer esto al revés, es decir, comprobar que el camino existe en el árbol ¿Cómo podría hacerlo? actualmente lo compruebo de la siguiente manera pero siempre me da de resultado verdadero: caso base que tiene que dar **true** `escamino([],Abn).`  caso recursivo `escamino([X|Xs],Abn) :- hazarbol(X,Xs,_,[Xs,X,_]), escamino(Xs,Abn).` y `escamino([X|Xs],Abn) :- hazarbol(X,_,Xs,[_,X,Xs]), escamino(Xs,Abn).`

Comment: No hay de qué. :) El problema es que en los casos generales mantienes el árbol original en la recursión, en lugar de quitar la raíz. Debería ser: `escamino([X|Xs],[L,X,_]) :- escamino(Xs,L).` y del mismo modo por la rama derecha. Ten en cuenta que si el camino es desde la raíz, puedes utilizar el predicado anterior `caminohasta/3` para comprobarlo, por ejemplo: `caminohasta(3,[[[[],3,[]],2,[]],1,[]],[1,2,3])`. En caso contrario, debes añadir otros dos casos generales por si la raíz no coincide con la cabeza del camino: `escamino(Xs,[L,_,_]) :- escamino(Xs,L).` y lo mismo con el derecho.

Comment: No me había dado cuenta de que estaba manteniendo el mismo árbol, cierto ! Gracias :)

Comment: Hola buenas José Antonio, me podrías ayudar con esta pregunta ?? Muchas gracias de todas maneras por tu ayuda hasta ahora :) https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/74503/intercambiar-nodos-en-un-%c3%a1rbol-prolog